# DNN Site azure DevOps build pipeline error

Tags: azure, azure-devops, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7, dnn9

I have DNN site package , i pushed the code into Azure DevOps repository.

If we want to create build pipeline for the DNN site package we need to add below Task.

**1.NuGet Restore
2. Set DNN Version Number
3. Build Solution
4. Test Assemblies
5. Copy Files
6. Publish Artifacts**

Here my question is , When i am trying add build solution task , we need to give solution path(.sln or .csproj).But DNN site has only packages so i am getting below error

**ERROR** : [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7A4u.png)

Comment: What code exactly is pushed?

Comment: we don't have any code in the repository, we have only a package.

Answer (score 0):

You should confirm that whether there is a `xxx.sln` file under your current repo. If not, you should push it into the repo.

**Besides**,check into your current repo, and determine which branch your project is in, based on that, you should check whether you select the right branch which the solution exists under the pipeline.

[image]

**Also**, you could specify all `csproj` files rather than a `sln` file to check if that works.

[image]

Comment: In my repository I don't have " .sln "  or ".csproj" file, basically, the DNN site has only a package, this is the reason we don't have ".sln" file in the repository.